How to create a file with IEEE single/double format data values using python?
I have a .dat file that is a binary file with a regular structure. Length of one
entry - 20 bytes. Each entry contains:

date/time (8 bytes, IEEE double format 12/30/1899 12:00 am)
humidity value (4 bytes, IEEE single format)
temperature value (4 bytes, IEEE single format)
additional value parameter (4 bytes, IEEE single format)

I read it using numpy and try to save the same file (without changes) using pandas:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bufType = np.dtype(
    [
        ('text', 'double'),
        ('a', 'single'),
        ('b', 'single'),
        ('c', 'single')
    ]
)

path = r'C:\Users\Егор\Desktop\ЛК-44\pool-исходник\ccc.dat'

data = np.fromfile(path, dtype=bufType)
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('my_file.dat')

but the created file contains different values ​​from the original ones, given that I did not change anything. I think this is because the original values ​​were saved in IEEE single format and IEEE double format, and in the new file in numpy.float32 and numpy.float64 format. What can I do to turn them into the desired format?

You're saving to a CSV, that's a text file, not binary.

If you want to get a file like the original, use data.tofile()
